# How to append to an array every minute on every reload of page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML code which is taking stock price which is updating every 1 minute ( on reload of page ). I want to make a graph out of the stock price. For this I would want to make an array in the morning and then as and when prices are updated every minute, the array is updated too. How can I do it? I tried to use local storage but just unable to get the desired results.

vwap_ltp_percentage is the variable here which I am getting every minute and which I want to append to an array

```
    vwap_ltp_array = Array()
    vwap_ltp_array.push(vwap_ltp_percentage)
    console.log(vwap_ltp_array)
    if (localStorage.getItem('test') == null) {
        localStorage.setItem('test',[])
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem('test',[])
    }
    localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(vwap_ltp_array))
    console.log(localStorage)
```

ge)

Comment: What is the purpose of an if/else construct, if you are doing the exact same thing in both branches?

Comment: If you always start with `vwap_ltp_array = Array()`, then you can't expect this to assemble more items over time. You need to start with _reading_ the array that might already be stored in localStorage, and only initialize the variable as a new empty array, if there wasn't one.

Comment: You want to use a server to do this, and then you can point your front-end code to a server endpoint to recover the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you are always starting with an empty array, the `if...else` construct is not doing anything...
Instead, you need to construct the initial array from the storage if an entry exists there.

```
    var testString = localStorage.getItem('test');
    vwap_ltp_array = testString ? JSON.parse(testString) : []
    vwap_ltp_array.push(vwap_ltp_percentage)
    localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(vwap_ltp_array))
    console.log(localStorage)
```